# AWS S3 bucket alarm revoke action

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a bucket with an object lock policy, for security reasons.

The problem is, I don't want the bucket to accidentally grow to hundreds of gigabytes for which I will have to pay for a long long time.

Is there a way using an alarm or any suitable amazon service to revoke access to a user if a bucket exceeds a certain size (or any other solution to this problem)?

Comment: You can activate bucket metrics which will publish a metric to cloudwatch which you then could monitor via an alarm: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/metrics-dimensions.html

Comment: Along with what @luk2302 has suggested, you can use lifecycle rules if you have objects which can be deleted after a certain time to limit costs.

Comment: Can an alarm trigger a revoke of access keys?

Comment: Nothing built-in for that. You would need to write that yourself, e.g. in python, deploy it as a lambda and let it get triggered by the alarm.

Comment: @luk2302 Is it an overkill to trigger a lambda on every put event?

Comment: That would be a different approach but no, that is not overkill at all.

Comment: @luk2302 Pardon me, I am not able to find what you suggested. I went to the options to create an alarm when the bucket is of certain value but there are no actions for attaching it to a lambda. In the lamba options, I can find the s3 put but not anything relevant to the alarm.

Comment: @luk2302 I think I figured it out now, it is done via the SNS topic.